# .htaccess rewrite url with get parameter

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

this is my first time to try .htaccess

this is what i want.

```
example.com/account/blitzen12 -> example.com/account/index.php?id=10&name=blitzen12
```

i don't want to include the id in rewriting, is it possible?

```
Note: id and name which is 10 and blitzen12 is retrive from the database.
```

so far this is what I've tried but it didn't work.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks  
RewriteEngine On 

RewriteRule ^account/(.*)$ ./account/index.php?page=account&id=$1&name=$2 [L,NC]
```

html code.

```
<a href="account/index.php?id=10&name=blitzen12">blitzen12</a>
```

can anyone help me with this? Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The "10" or the id, isn't part of the URL:

```
example.com/account/blitzen12
```

So you can't rewrite it into another URL, can't pull it out of thin air. You'll either need to just serve the page without an "id" (and pull it out of the database using the "name") or embed it in the URL without the query string, something like:

```
example.com/account/10/blitzen12
```

then you'd be able to rewrite it using:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks  
RewriteEngine On 

RewriteRule ^account/([0-9]+)/(.*)$ ./account/index.php?page=account&id=$1&name=$2 [L,NC]
```

Comment: I tried what you mention above but it didnt work.
for reference i'll edit and include html as well..

Comment: is it possible to rewrite html responses? i'm not sure if it's called outbound rule?

Comment: @blitzen12: mod_rewrite works on _requests_ reaching the server; it has nothing whatsoever to do with HTML. If you want your link URLs in your HTML to be of a specific form, then _you_ have to see to it that they are of that form.