# htaccess rewrite specific parameter with dot

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have an issue to rewrite url which is like:

```
http://examplepage.com/news/?aid=n_557eb95ed07360.45147988
```

to

```
http://examplepage.com/some-other-name
```

but it needs to be only this url if parameter changes it should do nothing. I think the problem is the dot in the parameter?

My current .htaccess for this matter is like this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^aid=n_557eb95ed07360.45147988$
RewriteRule ^news/$ /some-other-url [NC,L]
```

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [.htaccess rewrite url with get parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22853076/htaccess-rewrite-url-with-get-parameter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Drakes said, adding an escape to the dot should do the trick.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^aid=n_557eb95ed07360\.45147988$
RewriteRule ^news/$ /some-other-url [NC,L]
```

Or, if `aid` is going to be dynamic, then you can use:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^aid=(.*)$
```

And if you want to search for `aid` is any part of the query:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)aid=(.*)$
```

Comment: Thank a lot. Drakes solution was the way, but with this i can filter those param values.

Answer (score 0):

Escape the dot with `\.` to match a literal dot, not "any character".

A `.` means "[match any character](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html)" in a regular expression, so

```
/^aid=n_557eb95ed07360.45147988$/
```

will match

```
aid=n_557eb95ed07360.45147988
aid=n_557eb95ed07360045147988
aid=n_557eb95ed07360145147988
aid=n_557eb95ed07360245147988
...
```

but

```
/^aid=n_557eb95ed07360\.45147988$/
```

will only match

```
aid=n_557eb95ed07360.45147988
```

**Demo:** [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/oY0yW7/1)

Comment: No problem. You just wrote in your question "it needs to be **only** this url if parameter changes it should do nothing"