# Enable human readable URL's in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

Preface: Yes this question seems like duplicated, and I found related questions, but answers from there didnt help to me. :(

Hello, I want to add human readable URL's support for my PHP project. For now my URL quesry string looks like:

```
index.php?url=main/index
```

I would like to make it looks like:

```
index.php/main/index
```

I read following articles:

[Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18162686/url-rewrite-get-parameters)

[Cheatsheet](http://www.cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/mod-rewrite/)

[Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7677070/htaccess-rewrite-get-variables)

[Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22853076/htaccess-rewrite-url-with-get-parameter)

But when I do this:

```
var_dump($_GET['url']); // get empty array
```

, get empty array like no url parameter added.

My current `.htaccess`:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [NC]
```

Can somebody help me please? Thanks!

Comment: Does the URL still rewrite but doesn't pass through the url in $_GET?

Comment: Is your htaccess in root folder or in a subfolder ? Also, you'll have to add a condition to avoid a loop

Answer (score 5, accepted):

URL: `http://domain.com/index.php/controller/action`

Rewritten URL: `http://domain.com/index.php?url=controller/action`

`.htaccess`

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^index.php/(.*)$ /index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Explanation:

The `.*` in the pattern `^index.php/(.*)$` matches everything after `index.php/` on the incoming URL. The parentheses helps to capture the part as variable `$1`, which is then added at the end of the substitution URL `/index.php?url=` + `$1`.

`[L, QSA]`:
L ignore other rewrite rules, if this fits. 
QSA means query string append.

Comment: Hello, thanks for repply but actually I want revrse convertion, from `index.php?url=cont/action` to `index.php/cont/action`

Comment: or it mean that server will get as second but I can write it like in first case?

Comment: Maybe i got the question wrong. Not sure. This will rewrite the first URL `http://domain.com/index.php/controller/action` to `http://domain.com/index.php?url=controller/action` - and `$_GET['url']` will contain the string `controller/action`.

Comment: yes, you got write, but it doesnt work, $_GET aray still empty.

Comment: I replace my htaccess file with that yoy are sent, but it doesnt work, maybe I need add some extra configuration?

Comment: Hmm, whats the output of `var_dump($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);`?

Comment: it outputs `'/project/index.php/test/about'`

Comment: The full request_uri doesn't contain a `url=` part and so `$_GET['url']` is not set at all. (For better debugging of the rewrite rule, you could raise the Apache log level to see the url rewriting events in the log. Maybe they are not triggered.)

Comment: Hello, I enable this line in apache2.conf but in `/var/log/apache2/error.log` I cant seee any errors related to mode rewrite, and `tail -f error_log|fgrep '[rewrite:'` from apache2 docs return info about no found files

Comment: Maybe add the relevant part of your apache error log to the question. Is it possible that the index.php file is in a subfolder `projects`? If so, please adjust the substitution url, e.g. `/projects/index.php?url=$1`.

Comment: @excluded if REQUEST_URI output '/project/index.php/test/about' try to change the htaccess from RewriteRule ^index.php/(.*)$ /index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA] to RewriteRule ^/project/index.php/(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]

Comment: @JensA.Koch I think that the real issue is that the OP doesn't understand what he is doing. Your answer is right, but I guess the OP is still using `index.php?url=controller/action` in his code instead of `index.php/controller/action`.

Answer (score 2):

You have

```
index.php?url=main/index
```

Yuo want to rewrite (and then user redirect) to this

```
index.php/main/index
```

What about trying this?

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^url=([a-z]+)/([a-z]+)$
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://mydomain.site/index.php/%1/%2 [R=302,L]
```

R=301 or 302 depend on your need

On this example i assumed that on the original url there are only a-z chars.
Just to clarify (due the fact generally the process is inverse) on this way the users will be redirect, this rules does not convert links on your page.

Comment: hello, thanks for reply but this doesnt help to me. I do this stuff in htaccess maybe I should move to virtual host configuration?

Comment: i have a doubt, what type of link do the users on site see?

Answer (score 1):

In line
`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [NC]` the (.*) matches the part of the url up to '?' where the query begins.
To use the values passed in the query you need the QSA flag. Means Query String Append.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer, now line looks like:
`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [NC, QSA]`, but still have same result

Answer (score 0):

[image]Try the below code, Only considered for index.php you can replace it as per your requirement. Let me know if you need further assistance.

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(index\.php)/([0-9a-zA-Z\/_-]{1,99}) index.php?url=$2
```

What worked for me is:-
 `<?php var_dump($_GET); ?>`  this is the only thing I did on url `http://localhost/baba.php/abcd` . and original .htaccess file

`DirectoryIndex baba.php
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(baba\.php)*/([0-9a-zA-Z\/_-]{1,99}) baba.php?url=$2`

Comment: I did on my localhost, and It worked I tested it for baba.php and changed it to index.php for you, ok,I will try again and modify my answer.

Comment: damn, still not working, could you please screen with results? maybe I really doing something wrong...

Comment: @excluded have you tried the updated one or solved let us know.

Answer (score 0):

If Your URL : www.abcd.com/index.php/abcd/...

```
.htaccess

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

For Magento 2.4 Magento will always drop any GET parameters from the URL in a htaccess rewrite. The only way I found to make it work was to create a rewrite module. The setup is here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/158811/109113