# .htaccess rules to support three different types of URL schemes

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have three different types of URL schemes in my website:

1. `http://example.com/page.php`
2. `http://example.com/anotherpage.php/23` where `23` is the id and is being captured as GET data.
3. `http://example.com/yetanotherpage.php/23/somedata` where `23` and `somedata` is being captured as GET data.

What I need as a .htaccess rule is whatever comes after `example.com/` should be considered as PHP page, such that:

1. `http://example.com/page.php` be converted to `http://example.com/page`
2. `http://example.com/anotherpage.php/23` be converted to `http://example.com/anotherpage/23`
3. `http://example.com/yetanotherpage.php/23/somedata` be converted to `http://example.com/yetanotherpage/23/somedata`

I was able to write rules for #1 but didn't find anything for #2 and #3.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9694337/1084917

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14786531/1084917

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22853177/1084917

Comment: https://github.com/dayitv89/base_php